# Underlying logic of camera's native code

Tags: android, android-camera, android-source

I'm trying to better understand the underlying logic of camera's native code, but I appear to be hitting a dead-end when looking for the method definition for `Camera::connect()` and other functions declared from `Camera.h`.

The steps I've followed are these:

1. In the master branch [I located `Camera.java`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/hardware/Camera.java), which contains the logic for resolving cameras, selecting `CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK` when it is encountered:

   - `Camera.open()` calls `Camera.getCameraInfo(int, CameraInfo)` for each int in `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()`.
   - `Camera.getCameraInfo(int, CameraInfo)` in turn calls the native function `Camera._getCameraInfo(int, CameraInfo)`.
2. Delving [into the JNI](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/jni/android_hardware_Camera.cpp):

   - `android_hardware_Camera_getCameraInfo(JNIEnv*, jobject, jint, jobject)` then invokes the static method `Camera::getCameraInfo(jint, CameraInfo*)`, which appears to be declared through:

     ```
     #include <camera/Camera.h>
     ```
3. Browsing and searching the master branch doesn't seem to give any hits for `camera/Camera.h`. The only result I could find was in older tags, for instance [in the gingerbread branch](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/gingerbread/include/camera/Camera.h). Here there's only a method declaration:

   ```
   static  status_t    getCameraInfo(int cameraId,
                                 struct CameraInfo* cameraInfo);
   ```
4. However, the method body doesn't appear to be defined anywhere.

The last two steps are where I am confused. Where is `camera/Camera.h` defined for more recent versions of Android? And finally, where are the method bodies of `Camera` actually defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ICS, the Camera::getCameraInfo(jint, CameraInfo*) is defined in frameworks/av/camera/Camera.cpp as

```
status_t Camera::getCameraInfo(int cameraId,
                               struct CameraInfo* cameraInfo) {
    const sp<ICameraService>& cs = getCameraService();
    if (cs == 0) return UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    return cs->getCameraInfo(cameraId, cameraInfo);
}
```

Then it grabs a binder object of `CameraService` and call the `getCameraInfo` on `CameraService`.

```
status_t CameraService::getCameraInfo(int cameraId,
                                      struct CameraInfo* cameraInfo) {
    ...
    struct camera_info info;
    status_t rc = mModule->get_camera_info(cameraId, &info);
    ...
    return rc;
}
```

The `mModule` contains the actual implementation of camera on your device. Different devices may have different implementations. For example you can find `QualcommCamera` under [hardware/qcom/camera/QualcommCamera.cpp](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/hardware/qcom/camera/+/android-4.2.2_r1/QualcommCamera.cpp).

Then take a look at `connect`. The `connect` does a similar work and finally calls `CameraService::connect`. In that method, there is a `CameraClient` initialized by the `mModule`. So when you do something with the Client, you are actually working with the device-specific implementation.

One more word, the mModule is initialized by `hw_get_module` in `CameraService::onFirstRef`.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that after Gingerbread, some code moved to a different framework. [I located `camera/Camera.h` in the `platform/frameworks/av` repository.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/include/camera/Camera.h)

I found the definition of the method body [in `Camera.cpp`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/av/+/master/camera/Camera.cpp).