# Android Camera Release Time

Tags: android, camera, seconds

Good Day Everyone.

Im developing application and i use 2 screens and both of them uses camera feature with surface view onCreate method. I searched the net and didn't find any answer to cover my curiosity. I need to know in exact.

**How many seconds does android main thread needs to release the camera and start the new one? (Im swapping between above written activities).**

Because my application crashes after i try to start second activity and as far as i know java is the quickest code in world. Can anybody give Quick info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will vary between devices in any case, so you're better off not using some sort hardcoded delay before switching activities. Better to use [a method such as the one described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862621/how-to-check-if-camera-is-opened-by-any-application) to see if the camera is available (released by your first activity in your case) before triggering the `Intent` to start your new activity.

Comment: Glad to hear it. Please accept the answer if it helped. Good luck!