# Check which camera is Open Front or Back Android

Tags: java, android, camera

I know i can set a `boolean flag while opening front Camera`. And if flag is true it means front camera is on.

But is there a way using Android API to know which Camera is Open right now? Front or Back.

```
public int getFrontCameraId() {
    CameraInfo ci = new CameraInfo();
    for (int i = 0 ; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
        Camera.getCameraInfo(i, ci);
        if (ci.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) return i;
    }
    return -1; // No front-facing camera found
}
```

Camera Preview is inverting(upside donw) when i open Front Camera. So i have to add a check which Camera is open `if FrontCamera is opened then matrix = 270. otherwise matrix =90.`

**onPreviewFrame(byte abyte0[] , Camera camera)**

```
 int[] rgbData = YuvUtils.decodeGreyscale(abyte0, mWidth,mHeight);

    editedBitmap.setPixels(rgbData, 0, widthPreview, 0, 0, widthPreview, heightPreview);

    finalBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(editedBitmap, 0, 0, widthPreview, heightPreview, matrix, true);
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862621/how-to-check-if-camera-is-opened-by-any-application

Answer (score 1):

```
    private boolean safeCameraOpen(int id) {
    boolean qOpened = false;

    try {
        releaseCameraAndPreview();
        mCamera = Camera.open(id);
        qOpened = (mCamera != null);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(getString(R.string.app_name), "failed to open Camera");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return qOpened;    
}

private void releaseCameraAndPreview() {
    mPreview.setCamera(null);
    if (mCamera != null) {
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
    }
}
```

Since API level 9, the camera framework supports multiple cameras. 
If you use the legacy API and call open() without an argument, you get the first rear-facing camera.
Android devices can have multiple cameras, for example a back-facing camera for photography and a front-facing camera for video calls. 
Android 2.3 (API Level 9) and later allows you to check the number of cameras available on a device using the `Camera.getNumberOfCameras()` method.
To access the primary camera, use the `Camera.open()` method and be sure to catch any exceptions, as shown in the code below:

```
/** A safe way to get an instance of the Camera object. */
public static Camera getCameraInstance(){
    Camera c = null;
    try {
        c = Camera.open(); // attempt to get a Camera instance
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        // Camera is not available (in use or does not exist)
    }
    return c; // returns null if camera is unavailable
}
```

On devices running Android 2.3 (API Level 9) or higher, you can access specific cameras using Camera.open(int).
 The example code above will access the first, back-facing camera on a device with more than one camera.

Comment: Do not forget to release the Camera after using it by `Camera.release()`

Comment: 'android.hardware.Camera' is deprecated

Comment: @Gaan_setaglA that's just because of the new Camera2 API which is barely supported by any phones apart from the latest Nexus devices.

Answer (score 1):

In new [`android.hardware.camera2`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html) package, you can enquire from [`CameraCharacteristics.LENS_FACING`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraCharacteristics.html#LENS_FACING) property and each `CameraDevice` publishes its `id` with [`CameraDevice.getId()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraDevice.html#getId()) it's easy to get to the characteristics.

In the older camera API, I think the only way is to keep track of the index you opened it with.

```
private int cameraId;

public void openFrontCamera(){
   cameraId = getFrontCameraId();
   if (cameraId != -1)
     camera = Camera.open(cameraId); //try catch omitted for brevity
}
```

Then use `cameraId` later, this [little snippet](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setRotation(int)) might be a better way of achieving what you are trying to:

```
public void onOrientationChanged(int orientation) {
     if (orientation == ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN) return;
     android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo info =
            new android.hardware.Camera.CameraInfo();
     android.hardware.Camera.getCameraInfo(cameraId, info);
     orientation = (orientation + 45) / 90 * 90;
     int rotation = 0;
     if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
         rotation = (info.orientation - orientation + 360) % 360;
     } else {  // back-facing camera
         rotation = (info.orientation + orientation) % 360;
     }
     mParameters.setRotation(rotation);
 }
```

Comment: where should i put the code or call it onOrientationChanged

Comment: Follow the link "little snippet"

Answer (score 0):

if you have a custom Camera Activity you can try this method.

```
boolean inPreview;
```

in your on surfaceChanged method from surfaceView set

```
inPreview = True;
```

in your Camera.CallbackListener variable set

```
inPreview = false;
```