# How to check camera Id (primary or secondary) which camera is open currently in android when user capture an image?

Tags: java, android, android-camera

How to check camera type(primary or secondary) when user clicks an image in android?

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        fileUri = Utility.getOutputMediaFileUri(MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE, mContext);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

Comment: You could check the properties of both cameras and see which one it matches...

Comment: Please put your code in your post. Not in a comment. Moreover its unreadable now.

Comment: `when user clicks an image` ?????

Comment: @Vijendrapatidar Also, that class is deprecated. Please use the correct API. https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/CameraManager.html seems to be what you are looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't check in this context. That intent is supposed only to return a capture. If you attempt to open another camera with `Camera.open()` your app will crash.

You should implement a custom camera capture activity, in which you can have full control and also camera object. Then check on camera object which one is used.

Comment: Yes, but right now for this any temporary solution?

Comment: you can try here: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29772373/check-which-camera-is-open-front-or-back-android)

Comment: This is definitely the best solution! However, it doesn't actually answer the question!

Answer (score 1):

> How to check camera type(primary or secondary) when user clicks an image in android?

You don't. The image is the image. Whether it was taken by the front-facing camera, the rear-facing camera, a USB-connected camera, an IP camera, or is just some piece of clip art, is up to the camera app that happened to take this picture. There are hundreds of different camera apps, both pre-installed and user-installed.

Answer (score 0):

If the returned image has [EXIF header](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/ExifInterface), you can parse it to find the camera characteristics. Most likely, you will be able to determine whether it was taken with the front-facing or rear-facing camera.

Often, the rear-facing camera has higher resolution, and you can simply check if the photo resolution fits this. Note that on most built-in camera apps, **MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE** intent does not allow the user to  choose camera resolution, so the photo will be of default size.