# How to find the application that is using camera?

Tags: java, android, service, camera, handler

I'm doing an Android application that discovers if an app is using the camera in background.

Thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38941855/9643103), I can find if an app is using the Camera in your Android phone, so my code looks like this:

```
CameraManager manager = (CameraManager) getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
@Override
           public void onCameraAvailable(@NonNull String cameraId) {
               super.onCameraAvailable(cameraId);
               //Camera is not used
           }

           @Override
           public void onCameraUnavailable(@NonNull String cameraId) {
               super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraId);
               //Camera is used
           }
       }, new Handler());
```

But now I've found a problem: how can I find **the app** that is using the camera (as "app" I mean the Package Name of the app)? I've tried using 
 `manager.[something]`, wishing that the automatic hints in Android Studio could help me, without success.

Can you help me?

If you need further information, just ask me.

Thanks in advance,

F.

Comment: To my best of knowledge I don't think at this point, it is possible to get the owner of camera programmatically.

Comment: @AmitK.Saha neither changing the code?

Comment: not possible in android os.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible what you're asking for.

The two solutions are:
(1) modify Android Source and add new methods to CameraManager (and other methods in other components)
(2) use Xposed Framework (that needs Root Permissions) and create a Module that listens for "openCamera()" events and save the caller PackageName for later use when you will want to know who was the last caller.

Comment: Changing what code? The OS? For sure! But if you don't want to change Android Source, then you cannot achieve what you want to do.