# How to understand the camera on or off now?(android api 29)

Tags: java, android, android-camera

I want to understand the camera is on/off in android. I use android api 29, I found examples only for earlier versions. 
My background service is collecting data on the work of other apps at the moment, I need to know if the camera is on or not. I don't need to use camera. I just need status.

This other example, I don't understand, how it work.

```
private void registerCameraState() {
    cm = (CameraManager)getSystemService(Context.CAMERA_SERVICE);
    handler = new Handler();
    cm.registerAvailabilityCallback(new CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraAvailable(String cameraId) {
            super.onCameraAvailable(cameraId);
            isCameraOpened = false;
        }
        @Override
        public void onCameraUnavailable(String cameraId) {
            super.onCameraUnavailable(cameraId);
            isCameraOpened = true;
        }
    },handler);
}
```

I need info off/on camera on phone.

Comment: I think you need to know the status of the camera, refer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862621/how-to-check-if-camera-is-opened-by-any-application)

Comment: The example you found, lets your app to know if a camera device becomes available or unavailable at runtime. When a camera device is available, your app can open this camera device. At this moment, other apps will not be able to open the camera device until your app releases the camera. If you want to know, whether your app opened the camera, you must rely on your private logic.

Comment: @AlexCohn 

My background service is collecting data on the work of other apps at the moment, I need to know if the camera is on or not. I don't need to use camera, I just need status.

Comment: So, it seems that the `CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback` is exactly what you need.

Answer (score 0):

In general I recommend you to read the [Camera API Guide](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera) for API level 21 or greater.
There you can find featuring information and this piece of code:

```
/** Check if this device has a camera */
private boolean checkCameraHardware(Context context) {
    if (context.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)){
        // this device has a camera
        return true;
    } else {
        // no camera on this device
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is about the existence of a camera on the phone, I need status info:
camera on or off.