# Is there a way to detect if other app is using the camera?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I'm trying to make an app that protect android device from phishing app in which users have applied permission by accident.
The app detects camera activation by other app,
and it deactivate the camera if the camera is activated by other app.

**So is there a way to know if the camera is on?
and is there a way to disable the camera?**

I found `CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback`, but I am not sure if it is available in current versions.

Also I tried to find a way to disable camera but could not find it.

Also there are some camera block apps like "Camera Block: Guard & Anti spy" by BytePioneers where it stops camera before an app tries to use it. I am curious how this kind of app work.

Comment: You can register a `CameraManager.AvailabilityCallback` to receive callbacks when the camera becomes unavailable or available.

Answer (score 0):

**Is there a way to know if the camera is on?**

There be no straight way for an Android app to detect if another app is using the camera. Android's security model prohibit one app from accessing the resources or monitoring the behavior of another app without explicit permission and appropriate APIs.

While Android does provide APIs for accessing certain system information, such as the list of running processes or the usage statistics of other apps, these APIs have limitations and privacy considerations. They may not provide fine-grained information about whether a specific app be actively using the camera at any given moment.

Furthermore, even if you could detect that another app be using the camera, accessing or interfering with its operation would likely be a violation of the Android platform's security principles and may lead to your app being flagged as potentially harmful or intrusive.

If have concerns about privacy or resource usage related to the camera, it be best to address them within your own app's functionality and not attempt to monitor or interfere with other apps' behavior. Additionally, if believe an app be misbehaving or violating user privacy, can report it to the appropriate platform or store for investigation.

**Is there a way to disable the camera?**

Disabling the camera programmatically on Android be not a straightforward task, especially considering Android's security model, which prioritizes user privacy and app sandboxing. System-level permissions be typically required to manipulate hardware features such as the camera, and such permissions be not available to third-party apps for security reasons.

However, if you have control over the device's firmware or system settings (for example, if ye be developing a custom ROM or managing devices in an enterprise environment), may be able to disable the camera through device policies or modifications to the system software.

Here be some potential approaches to consider:

Device Administration: Device Administration APIs to enforce policies on Android devices, including disabling certain features such as the camera. However, this requires the app to be designated as a device administrator, and users must grant permission for these privileges.

Custom ROMs: If developing custom firmware for Android devices (e.g., custom ROMs), you may be able to modify the system settings or firmware to disable the camera functionality. This approach requires advanced knowledge of Android system development and may not be feasible for all devices.

Enterprise Device Management: In enterprise environments, mobile device management (MDM) solutions can be used to enforce policies on managed devices, including disabling certain hardware features like the camera. MDM solutions typically provide APIs or management consoles to configure device policies remotely.

Rooting: Rooting an Android device provides superuser access, allowing for deeper system modifications. With root access, it may be possible to disable the camera through system-level changes. However, rooting voids device warranties and can compromise device security.

It be important to note that disabling critical features like the camera can have significant implications for device functionality and user experience. Additionally, any modifications made to the system software should be done carefully to avoid unintended consequences or security vulnerabilities.

As a general principle, apps developed for the Google Play Store should not attempt to disable or manipulate system features without user consent, as this violates Google's policies and may result in app removal or account suspension.

Reference link - [How to check if camera is opened by any application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15862621/how-to-check-if-camera-is-opened-by-any-application)

Comment: What’s with all the “ye”s? :)